# jsoup extract specific attribute from a hyperlink

Tags: java, jsoup

I have I some hyperlinks in a web page that I want to extract the attribute title which within it

I tried

```
 select("a[href]").attr("title")
```

but I get no thing

**Edit**

**The complete div here**
[image]
Trial code

```
 Elements es = doc.select("div.mini-placard")
 for(Element e:es) 
 {
    System.out.println(  e.select("span.align-image-vertically").select("a").attr("title"));
  }
```

no output !

Comment: What is your expected output? Post code snippet rather than screenshot

Comment: the  that the attribute title include  it ( a title has been written here)

Comment: Can you post what you tried and with the html snippet ? It will be easy to sorted .

Comment: @soorapadman I have  just posted it

Comment: Can you please post the url or the HTML fragment (no screenshot) you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

Please extract link element properly and then inspect attributes of the link element as below:

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/' title='hi'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkTitle = link.attr("title"); // 'hi'
```

[Courtesy](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Comment: No your code doesn't solve the problem. It works same as my code